# Loopback 4 shopping example throwing error

Tags: loopback, loopback4

Hello I just downloaded lb4 shopping example stated here https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-Tutorial.html#try-it-out.

I have run npm install. But when I run `npm run docker:start` its is giving following error

```
> loopback4-example-shopping-monorepo@1.1.1 docker:start D:\ionic-pr\loopback-projects\tryjwt\loopback4-example-shopping
> ./bin/start-dbs.sh

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

As form the code snipt you provided, It seems that you are using Windows OS and the .sh inside the loopback docker is shell script which are not executable on Windows. For this you may install cygwin, gitbash like supporters and shot a try.

Alternatively You can look to following if using win10 :

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I tried running it on both git bash and cygwin but getting same error